# Is there any available source code which is Windows 64 bit compatible that can disassemble binary code?

Tags: disassembly, windows, c++, c, intel

I'm writing a program that takes as input a single byte of binary (machine code from code segment) and converts it into assembly. I've done some searching online but have yet to find anything helpful. The source code must be compatible with Windows 8.1/10/11 targeting the Intel x86 architecture.

Comment: You'll need to know the CPU architecture that the assembled binary targets. Capstone Engine is on github and supports a variety of architectures. It may be useful for your needs.

Comment: Python module capstone-windows: https://pypi.org/project/capstone-windows/

Comment: More recent package for capstone that should work on windows too: https://pypi.org/project/capstone/

Comment: Hi and welcome to RE.SE. There are plenty of these libraries al around the web under various licenses, some more liberal than others. [zydis](https://zydis.re/) comes to mind. [Capstone](https://www.capstone-engine.org/) was already mentioned. [udis86](https://github.com/vmt/udis86) comes to mind as well as [bddisas](https://github.com/bitdefender/bddisasm) or [distorm](https://github.com/gdabah/distorm) and there are probably more I forgot or am not aware of.

Comment: If you need something, related specifically to Intel, you can use Intel XED, https://intelxed.github.io/ . This product comes from Intel itself and used in Intel and other companies products.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I'm pretty sure I'll find something that suits my interest from the many selections that you all have suggested.